# Dell XPS L502X cannot connect to external monitor

Tags: windows-7, graphics-card, multiple-monitors, bios, external-display

I have Dell XPS L502X Laptop with windows 7 64 bit. I accidentally broke my display and I can connect to external monitor. The only problem is that I cannot see anything before the log in screen. I want to install a new windows but since I cannot see anything i.e. I cannot access the bios/ bios does not appear in the external monitor. Because of this I( cannot access the bios and install another windows. I want a fresh install as I have to format my hard disk completely. Please tell me how could I view the bios in my external monitor with this laptop. And for your information it has an integrated nvidia graphics card, which doesn't show anything unless it's drivers are loaded in windows, so that's why it shows just as soon as the log in screen appears as the drivers has been loaded for it to work. Help appreciated.

Comment: What happens if you leave the laptop closed? (Mine powers up and uses the external screen when I do that).

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "close". If I shut it down or restart it, it boots into the bios. If I keep the lid closed, it gets into the sleep mode and I have to press the enter button to get to the logon screen.

Comment: I meant opening the lid, pressing the power button and closing the lid before the laptop has started windows.  (Shutting down, hibernating, sleep, doing nothing etc are all option which you can configure in windows, but right after power up windows should not be loaded yet, so you can safely close the lid without hibernate disadvantage).

Comment: Nothing happens.